# How to create 3 subplots for boxplots on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot, subplot

```
df2020 = transport_data.loc['2020']
df2021 = transport_data.loc['2021']
df2022 = transport_data.loc['2022']

fig = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,7))
ax = [
    plt.subplot(121),
    plt.subplot(122)]
df2020.boxplot(grid=False, rot=90, fontsize=10, ax = ax[0])
df2021.boxplot(grid=False, rot=90, fontsize=10, ax = ax[1])
ax[0].set_ylabel('Types of Passengers', fontsize = '12')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Number of Passengers', fontsize = '12')
ax[0].set_title('2020')
ax[1].set_title('2021')
```

How do I make 3 subplots for boxplots? I've filtered my original dataset(transport_data) based on its years (2020,2021 and 2022) and I want to make 3 subplots for each year. This is kinda what my boxplot looks like rn[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyG0M.png)

Comment: Is your request to increase the two subplots to 3? As you already have 2, why not increase it to 3, is there a challenge?

Comment: Yeah, just rewrite your `ax` into `ax = [plt.subplot(131), plt.subplot(132), plt.subplot(133)]` and do the same steps for the third year